# Execute a custom script when OS X 10.8 is in Power nap?

Tags: macos, applescript, power-nap, automation

Apple new feature of OS X 10.8 in new Macs "Power Nap" checks email and does make backups.

Is it possible to execute a **custom script** (bash, AppleScript,...) when OS X 10.8 is in Power nap mode? For example pull a git repository or download files.

Comment: `log show --last 7h --predicate 'subsystem == "powerd"' | grep "DarkWake"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, it's **not** possible.

The reason is that *Power Nap* doesn't have an API that 3rd party apps can hook into (so apps could trigger a wake event or be notified when one occurs).

Whether this will remain like that in the future depends upon Apple. It would be interesting to see if there's a simple way to detect when one is in *power nap* mode, but doesn't seem to be available *afaik*.

If you leave a script that pulls from git every minute, in theory, since *Power Nap* is really a power on without graphics and audio state, maybe it would get executed (if it was running before). *untested*.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11692367/2684

Comment: My tests show that it'll get executed, though the timing of powernap seems very random.